# How to select datetime date as dddd, dd mmmm, yyyy with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008, date-format

I have a table with a date column set as datetime. I am currently selecting and converting the date as follows which returns the following format: `dd mmm yyyy`

**Current (example):** 
23 Aug 2014

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), C.modTime, 106) AS modTime
```

Can someone tell me how I need to change this to get the following format instead: `dddd, dd mmmm yyyy`

**Required (example):** 
Saturday, 23 August 2014

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: you could use `FORMAT()` if on sql-server 2012 or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
DATENAME(dw, C.modTime) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), C.modTime, 106) AS modTime
```

which when run with the current value of getdate() yields:

Saturday, 23 Aug 2014

Or, constructing the entire string manually:

```
DATENAME(dw, C.modTime) + ', ' + 
cast(datepart(dd, C.modTime) as char(2)) + ' ' + 
datename(mm, C.modTime) + ' ' +
cast(datepart(yyyy,C.modTime) as char(4))
```

to get:
Saturday, 23 August 2014

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help - this works great ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, is there a way to get the month in full letters here as well so that I get August instead of Aug ?

Comment: @user2571510: Check my addition, to provide the whole month name.

Comment: Thanks again - it's perfect now !

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 or later

```
declare @d as datetime = '20140823'

select format(@d,'dddd, dd MMMM yyyy', 'en-US')
```

Result = Saturday, 23 August 2014

Comment: Thanks, sorry I am still on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Try this too:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) +  ', ' + STR(DAY(GETDATE()),2,1) + ' ' + DATENAME(M,GETDATE()) + ' ' + STR(YEAR(GETDATE()),4,1)
```